# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception for huge number of objects in array

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

When size of data is 600, there is no exceltion. 
When the size of the data is 800 I am getting following exception, after completing all the iterations and exiting the loop at following line:

```
'imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.getAppContext(), posters);'
```

Issue is not related to splitArray[] which is inside the loop. Please note that it works for smaller size data. 
Please help.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.udacityproject.svs.popularmovies, PID: 12517
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
at com.udacityproject.svs.popularmovies.MainActivity$1.deliverResult(MainActivity.java:130)
at com.udacityproject.svs.popularmovies.MainActivity$1.deliverResult(MainActivity.java:57)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:255)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:80)
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:487)
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:504)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Constructor for Image Adapter :

```
    public ImageAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Poster[] objects){
        super(context, 0, objects);
        posters = objects;
    }
```

Function:

```
    public void deliverResult(String[] data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Poster[] posters = new Poster[data.length];
            for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                String imagePath = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" ;
                int imageId;
                String title;
                String overview;
                String rating;
                String releaseDate;
                String[] splitArray;
                try {
                    splitArray = data[i].split("[*]");
                } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
                imagePath+=splitArray[2];
                imageId = Integer.valueOf(splitArray[0]);
                title = splitArray[1];
                rating = splitArray[3];
                overview = splitArray[4];
                releaseDate = splitArray[5];
                posters[i] = new Poster( imageId, imagePath, title, overview, rating, releaseDate);
            }
            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.getAppContext(), posters);
            mMoviePoster.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the `split` isn't returning what you expect .... All I can say is that you try to access `array[5]` where the `array.length == 5`. Please provide the content of `data[i]` where it fails. (add a `try-catch` and print the line that fails.). You can [edit] your question with that info

Comment: `splitArray[5]` is the problem. check the size of it

Comment: if (splitArray.length >= 5) {} - add this condition

Comment: If the problem lies in `new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.getAppContext(), posters);` then you should add the constructor of the class to your question. Also whenever you're getting an exception, show us the **stack trace**, not only the exception message.

Comment: Now what is at line 130? `releaseDate = splitArray[5];`?

Comment: @QBrute at line 130, imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.getAppContext(), posters); this line is there.

Comment: And what's in ImageAdapter constructor?

Comment: public ImageAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Poster[] objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        posters = objects;
    }

Comment: Everything in the constructor is ok. What's at line 57? `MainActivity.java:57`

Answer (score 2):

One of the line included between the 600th and 800th line is incomplete.

Add this following line :

```
assert splitArray.length > 4 : "Following line lacks a column: " + data[i];
```

after :

```
splitArray = data[i].split("[*]");
```

It should tell you which line lacks the fifth column

Comment: Can you please have a closer look at the question again ? Issue is after exiting the loop, not inside.

Comment: if assertion are activated. -ae I think

Comment: @codingcorgi please take a closer look to your bigger `data` array instead, The exception mention that size of the array that fails. And it is only 5 cells.